# mongoDB delete n documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a huge mongoDB collection with 1 million records.
Now , except some random 10k records , i would like to delete rest of the records.
Is there any way to delete all the records (except keeping 10k) in a single shot?
For example , we have rownum in oracle.  Is it even possible to do it in mongoDB

my sample collection :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5efe4fd0fe4we5e9000185c660a"),
    "modelNumber" : "517083bb-2b35-4fb9-b3b9-004101342418",
    "name" : "abc"
}
```

`db.collection.count()` gives me 1 milion records.

I want to wipe out all 1 million records except keeping some random 10k records.

Comment: To get exact count you need to use `countDocuments()`. You can use `deleteMany` or `Bulk.write` methods to delete many documents in a collection.

Comment: Hi Prasad , seems like you din't ready my question properly ,  i know the count and I know how to delete multiple documents ,  but i would like to know if I can delete based on something like rownum... so how do i delete all 1 million records except some random 10k records.

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot do it in a single shot. According to me you first have to use aggregation pipeline to filter out the id's of the documents you want to delete and then apply **deleteMany** with id's as filter.

Following code explains this:-

```
list_of_ids=db.collection.aggregate([{'$sample': {'size': 990000 }}, {'$project' : {'_id' : 1}} ]);
results = db.collection.delete_many({'_id': {'$in': list_of_ids}})
```

This is how you can achieve your result.

Answer (score 2):

Deleting almost 1 million records will take some time. As you like to keep 10k random documents, I assume these are some test-data. I would suggest to create a new collection with 10k documents and drop the not needed one:

```
db.collection.renameCollection('collection-old')
db.getCollection('collection-old').aggregate([
   { $limit: 10000 },
   { $merge: { into: 'collection' } }
])
db.getCollection('collection-old').drop()
```

Note, don't forget to create your indexes on new collection, if applicable.

When you use `$merge` then documents are merged with existing documents in case your application permanently inserts new documents.

Comment: thanks for the answer..creating new indexes is really painful.. especially if i have too many indexes to create.

Comment: For a collection of 10k documents it should not take too long - esp. compared to deleting 990000 rows. You can create all indexes with a single command: `db.runCommand({ createIndexes: 'collection', indexes: db.getCollection('collection-old').getIndexes() })`. Of course, you must run it before you drop the old collection.